# How do I project on the Dirac and Pauli structures?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices

I have a term which is $A_1\gamma^{\mu}+A_2 [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]p_\nu$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are constants and $p_\nu$ is a momentum where $p^2$ is much greater than zero. How can I project on the structures, I would like to get $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you  seeking something like $A_1 = {\rm tr}(\gamma^1 O)/4$, where $O$ is your expression?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find $A_1,A_2$ from the expression $$M_{\alpha\beta}^{\mu}=A_1\gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}+A_2\gamma^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}p_{\nu}$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are spinor indices and $$\gamma^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}=\sum_{\kappa}{\gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\kappa}\gamma^{\nu}_{\kappa\beta}}$$
Take the trace of $M^{\mu}$ with $\gamma_\mu$ and $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$ i.e. $$A_1=\frac{1}{2^{\lfloor D/2\rfloor}}\sum_{\alpha\beta}M^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}\gamma_{\mu\beta\alpha}$$ and
$$A_2p_\nu=\frac{1}{2^{\lfloor D/2\rfloor}}\sum_{\alpha\beta}M^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}\gamma_{\mu\nu\beta\alpha}$$
where $D$ is your spacetime dimension, probably $4$ in your case. In case of odd spacetime dimension summation over spinor indices needs a bit more case.

This property follows from orthogonality of trace in Clifford algebra and Clifford algebra being complete in terms of basis which are identity, gamma matrices $(\gamma^{\mu})$ and antisymmetric multiples of gamma $\gamma^{\mu\nu}, \gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}...$

For reference lookup Ch$-3$ of supergravity by Friedman and Proeyen.

Comment: Thank you! If I look at your solution with a naive approach, the first one tells me, I should take the trace of $M^\mu$ with $\gamma_\mu$ since the trace of odd numbers of $\gamma$ matrices is zero. Why do I have to take the trace of $M^\mu \gamma_{\mu\nu}$ in the second case and cannot just take the trace of $M^\mu$ itself?

Comment: @Nik But the trace of a commutator vanishes, by trace cyclicity.